# Error en Vista SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

```
CREATE VIEW VistaCenso AS
SELECT * FROM censo a
JOIN colegio b
ON a.dni = b.preside
JOIN municipio c 
ON b.nombre = c.nombre
WHERE ndistrito = '1'
ORDER BY a ASC;
```

Tiene el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  la columna «nombre» fue especificada más de una vez
```

Me tiene desquiciado. ¿Alguien sabría como resolverlo?

Comment: Hola. lo que sucede es que `SELECT * FROM ...` traerá todos los campos de las tablas a,b,c, por lo que en b y en c tienes el campo nombre y la vista intenta poner cada campo como una columna. Para que no te salag ese mensaje tienes que definir que campos quieres traer en la parte del SELECT, es decir `SELECT a.campo1, a.campo2, b.campo1, b.campo2, c.campo1, c.campo2, ... FROM ... `

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).

Comment: @AbrahamChan ponelo como respuesta... igual, tambien deberia agregar el as... algunas bases de datos renombran los campos automaticamnete cuando pasa esto.. se ve que la que esta usando no...

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que el campo "nombre" está en mas de una tabla.
La solución para esto es indicar en el select cuales columnas necesitas y en caso de que un campo se repita como lo es el nombre, puedes utilizar un alias para ellos.

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE VIEW VistaCenso AS
SELECT a.dni, b.nombre as nombre_colegio, c.nombre as nombre_municipio FROM censo a
JOIN colegio b
ON a.dni = b.preside
JOIN municipio c 
ON b.nombre = c.nombre
WHERE ndistrito = '1'
ORDER BY a ASC;
```

Algo así.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que **SELECT * FROM ...** traerá todos los campos de las tablas a, b, c y por lo que vemos en tu consulta en b y c tienes el campo nombre así que la vista intenta poner cada campo como una columna.

Para que no te salag ese mensaje **tienes que definir que campos quieres traer** en la parte del SELECT, es decir

```
SELECT a.campo1, a.campo2, b.campo1, b.campo2, c.campo1, c.campo2, ... FROM ...
```